# Transition maps on Grassmanian $Gr(2,5)$

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, grassmannian

I need to provide charts and transition maps on Grassmanian $(2,5)$. (All $2$-dimensional subspaces in $5$-dimensional space). I know how the charts look, used definition from this document:
http://people.math.umass.edu/~tevelev/5-20.pdf

Now I have to write explicit transition functions (well, at least for one pair of charts). As far as I understand, I don't know exact form of those $A_{ij}$ matrices, so I am unable to write something like $A_{i^{\prime}j^{\prime}}^{-1}A$.

Comment: I had describe the general construction here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194445/is-the-determinant-bundle-the-pullback-of-the-mathcal-o1-on-mathbb-pn-u/1683424#1683424! Otherwise, I can give you a more specific input. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why not take an order preserving transform. For example:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a&1&c&e&0\\b&0&d&f&1\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow \begin{bmatrix}1&a&0&c&e\\0&b&1&d&f\end{bmatrix} \ ?$$

Comment: Because this is not a valid transition map. I neet to provide 6 functions, like $a' = a'(a,b,c,d,e,f)$.